# My computer blue-screens when Windows is loading; what can I do?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bsod

I just built a new desktop for gaming. Every time I start the computer, it runs normally until Windows is loading, at which point it gets stuck on a blue screen. I've tried every possible way to repair it, including restoring Windows, but nothing seems to be working. I'm not sure if it's a compatibility problem or a BIOS issue or even the RAM, since the beep is a normal beep and the machine only blue-screens when loading Windows.

Machine specs:
i3 530 2.93 GHz
P7H55-M/USB3
Corsair Vengeance 4GB 1600MHz
iGame Gtx 460
Win 7 32bit
Huntkey X7 900W

Comment: First lets start with the contents of the blue screen. Was there a hex code or message? If so, what was it?

Comment: Is this a fresh installation of Windows 7, or did you swap out hardware for an existing installation?  Also, why a 32-bit OS instead of 64-bit OS?

Answer (score 0):

Can you start in safe mode? It sounds like a driver issue as it starts and then bluescreens.  Usually that could be the problem driver loading.